# WP plugin that compares prices from different vendors

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have been trying to find a price comparison plugin for WordPress. Does anybody know of any?

It just needs to be a simple plugin that can compare prices of the same product from different vendors - like a product manager plugin.

So, in frontend, the user can select a product, and then it will show all the vendors and their prices for this product in a list, sorted with the cheapest first.

this is an example of what I mean:

http://www.kinguin.net/category/10158/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor-the-dark-ranger-dlc-steam-key/

one product, but you can see all the vendors that sells it, and their respective prices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google knows the answer. This is just one that it gave me when I searched on Wordpress Plugin Price Comparison site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/price-comparison

Comment: Google was the first thing I did :) been searching for days. This is not what I am looking for though. Need something like in the link provided in the description, but thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

Will they be sold all from your website or links to other sites and I'm guessing you are entering all the prices manually if so you could try just a price table/comparison plugin